# How do rocket launch sites get liquid oxygen?

Tags: launch-site, lox

How do rocket launch sites obtain their liquid oxygen used for loading the oxygen tanks in the rockets?

A while ago I seem to remember reading something that implied SpaceX had equipment to generate liquid oxygen on-site from oxygen extracted from the air. But I don't know the details.

What equipment is used? How quickly does it generate liquid oxygen (L/hr)? Is it stored for long, or generated shortly before using it?

Comment: It looks like your question is pretty-well answered at the proposed duplicate site, but there might be a new question in here somewhere. Have a look at all the answers there and if you see something not covered you can update your question and focus on the unanswered aspects. *Welcome to Space!*

Comment: Re, "equipment to generate liquid oxygen...from the air." That's pretty much where _all_ LOX comes from--distilled from liquified air. Check out airproducts.com. I don't know how many players there are in that business, but they're one of the biggest if not _the_ biggest.  If delivery of LOX by truck from one of their existing plants to your site is not economical, then I bet you can negotiate with them for construction a new plant on your site.

Comment: Read [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_separation) about cryogenic air separation.